# Does AWS Aurora suffer from the same limitations that MySQL suffer from?

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-aurora

MySQL has a limitations max row size as 64kB.
I would like to know if Amazon Aurora, which is supposedly a drop in replacement for MySQL, shares the same limitation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, according to documentation from AWS:

> The Amazon Aurora database engine is designed to be wire-compatible
>   with MySQL 5.6 using the InnoDB storage engine.

http://aws.amazon.com/rds/aurora/faqs/#general

This means that innoDB limits applies:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-restrictions.html

Specifically for row size default limit is 8000B:

> The maximum row length, except for variable-length columns (VARBINARY,
>   VARCHAR, BLOB and TEXT), is slightly less than half of a database
>   page. That is, the maximum row length is about 8000 bytes for the
>   default page size of 16KB; if you reduce the page size by specifying
>   the innodb_page_size option when creating the MySQL instance, the
>   maximum row length is 4000 bytes for 8KB pages and 2000 bytes for 4KB
>   pages. LONGBLOB and LONGTEXT columns must be less than 4GB, and the
>   total row length, including BLOB and TEXT columns, must be less than
>   4GB.

Comment: Doesn't that also depends on which Aurora version is used? They must not have the same limits if they're not all backward compatible with mysql 5.6.

This answer is partial.